# Set a specific sheet in a spreadsheet as form destination

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I'm working on a University project with GAS and I'm stuck. I set a spreadsheet with some logic as destination to a form (I need to process the data coming from the form).

Here it is my code:

```
  // Create the form from a template in the folder just created
  var formFile = formTemplate.makeCopy('questionario', newFolder);
  var form = FormApp.openById(formFile.getId());

  // Create the spreadsheet from a template
  var repliesFile = responseTemplate.makeCopy('risposte', newFolder);
  var replies = SpreadsheetApp.openById(repliesFile.getId());

  // Set the destination spreadsheet for form replies
  form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, replies.getId());
```

My problem is that the form reply create a new sheet inside the spreadsheet, so my logic is not applied to the data coming from the form.

Any suggestion? Is there a way to put the data in the sheet I want? If there is not, can you suggest any workaround? Thank you all

[reply spreadsheet image with the two sheet, mine and the one created by the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97Dsu.png)

Comment: Use the onFormSubmit trigger to collect the data and put it into whatever spreadsheet you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to set a sheet as the destination of the forms responses because there is only one method to set the form destination:

[setDestination(type,id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#setdestinationtype,-id)

In order to put the data in the sheet that you want instead of using the built-in feature to send the respondes to a spreadsheet, use the form submit installable trigger and the corresponding event object

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/form
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Comment: Thank you Ruben, I'll take it into consideration. I'm evaluating the possibility to use formulas in my spreadsheet that refer to a sheet that is not present yet (so I can use the sheet created by default, just changing its name). Not sure wich is the easier path for me, I'll work on it. Thank you very much!